# Searching for menu entries in desktop environments other than Unity

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, shortcut-keys, search, accessibility

Does any other desktop environment have the type-to-search-application-menus feature found in Unity?

I’m curios about trying a more spartan desktop such as Xfce or LXDE. Or maybe something entirely different. But I want to keep the workflow where I can press the `Alt` key from any application and type my way to menu entries.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is the [HUD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD) (Heads Up Display) which is a special feature of Unity. At the moment, there's no other desktop or window manager with this functionality.